# Como inhabilites la depuración Ionic

Tags: android, ionic, apk

Estoy intentando subir mi app a la play store, pero cuando la voy a subir me aparece

**Cargaste un archivo APK o Android App Bundle que se puede depurar. Por razones de seguridad, es necesario que inhabilites la depuración para que el archivo se pueda publicar en Google Play. Obtén más información sobre los archivos APK o Android App Bundles que se pueden depurar.**

Segun la documentacion de Ionic deberia usar el comando

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

Pero ya lo utlize para armar mi apk y aun persiste el error.

Comment: Revisa que no tenga habiltiada la depuración: android:debuggable="true"

Answer (score 1):

Quizás deberías tener en cuenta la compilación con `--prod`

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

ya que por defecto se compila en modo development.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al mensaje:

> Cargaste un archivo APK o Android App Bundle que se puede depurar.

al parecer tienes habilitada la depuración, revisa en tu AndroidManifest.xml que no la tengas habilitada:

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Puedes desabilitarla

```
  android:debuggable="false"
```

o simplemente elimina este atributo de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`